# BCP on global ##temp table error

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I'm using the following query to write the data in a external file:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000);
select @sql = 'bcp tempdb.##hmscript out 
F:\HMS\test.txt -c -t, -T -S GIT2B-01\MON'
select @sql
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

When testing the bcp in cmd window I'm getting the following error:

SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 11525
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The metadata could
not be determined because statement 'select * from ##hmscript' uses a temp table.

Somebody has a solution for this?

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: Why are you using a global ##temp table? Since this effectively reduces concurrency to 1, just use a regular user table and drop it when you are done.

Comment: that was another option I was thinking about, but I guessed my curiosity took the upperhand and I wanted to try something :) But seeing it's quite a messy thing to do using global temp table, I'll switch to a normal table like you said

Comment: Does the ##hmsscript table exist when you run this script?  The tempdb database qualifier should be omitted since the ## prefix denotes tempdb.

Answer (score 0):

If the table doesn't exist, you'll get this error.

Create the table and try again, and you should get what you want.